# How to get the best K for self organizing maps "SOM" using Elbow method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, yellowbrick, clustering-key

I am trying to use SOM to cluster my data, firstly I want to get the best K. but I need a line or something to detect the best K on the plot. I tried to use KElbowVisualizer() but it always diplay an error:

> YellowbrickTypeError: The supplied model is not a clustering estimator; try a classifier or regression score visualizer instead!

and here is my code:

```
from sklearn_som.som import SOM
som = SOM(m = 1, n = i, dim = data.shape[1])
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(som, k = (1,11))
visualizer.fit(data)
visualizer.show()
```

I also used the ordinary Plot() from matplotlib, but I cannot see the Best k,
my code:

```
inertia = []
for i in range (1,31):
    som = SOM(m = 1, n = i, dim = data.shape[1])
    som.fit_predict(data)
    inertia.append(som.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1,31), inertia)
plt.title('elbow method for SOM')
plt.xlabel('number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

[that's the plot I got from Plot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aQjB.png)

So, please how can I do that either in the plot or by using a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found the best solution to my question. I decided to post it here. may be someone else needs it.

```
from kneed import KneeLocator
```

The solution is here
just use this library with the matplotlib library

the implementation is like that:

```
inertia = []
for i in range (1,31):
    som = SOM(m = 1, n = i, dim = x_lda_train.shape[1])
    som.fit_predict(x_lda_train)
    inertia.append(som.inertia_)
# identify the knee by using the kneelocator function
kneeloc1 = KneeLocator(range(1,11), wcss, curve='convex', direction='decreasing')
plt.plot(range(1,31), inertia)
plt.title('elbow method for SOM')
plt.xlabel('number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
# print it by using the vlines
plt.vlines(kneeloc1.knee, plt.ylim()[0], plt.ylim()[1], linestyles='dashed')
plt.show()
# you can see this also as just a number by printing it
print(kneeloc1.knee)
```

For more info you can see the documentation:
visit https://kneed.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameters.html